# Open Realm Browser on Live Database in Genymotion?

Tags: android, genymotion, realm

I'd like to monitor a Realm database while running an Android app on Genymotion -- rather than pulling it over and over again.

The most obvious possibilities would be to have the Realm database stored on external storage that's mounted to the local filesystem.  Or be able to open it directly in /data/data, but I just can't figure out how.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to share a Realm file between processes. It is an open issue (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1091).